# Linux Mint - open windows not showing up as icons on toolbar

Tags: linux, linux-mint

The toolbar is completely empty and when I run apps or open windows, the icons do not show up. The weird thing is when I select 'Panel Properties' and UNSELECT 'expand', then it shows up. But then my toolbar shrinks and doesnt go 100% in width.

Driving me crazy. Any ideas?

Comment: This is Linux Mint 10. I just installed it today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.. I had to right-click on taskbar and select Add Panel and then Windows List...  argh .

Comment: Thank you. Seriously this was not at all intuitive.. I think they should make this behavior default..